# Redirect url for facebook desktop app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, node-webkit

I am trying to develop a facebook desktop app using node webkit. I am trying to find a way to use facebook client side Javascript sdk to access graph functionalities. I am using the following code to try and connect to facebook. (https://gist.github.com/konsumer/2298cc4f8b7b0a1ee9fa#file-nwfacebooklogin-js)

However when I give the redirect URL as https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html it gives an error `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

What is the URL I should give since I wont be hosting this on a website.

Comment: Have you configured any "Website" platforms in your Application Settings? This could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. I did 'Sign in with facebook' by opening a new tab on our servers, on approved domain (add it to the facebook 'App Domains').

To pass the login data, I opened the new tab using

```
var login_window = window.open(url,{
    "position": "center",
    "focus": true
});
```

Then, on that page, after redirecting back from facebook, after receiving the access token, I saved in in the page `sessionsStoragee` and accessed it from the first tab using:

```
login_window.window.sessionStorage.login_data
```